# 'int main(int, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)' takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]

Tags: c++

c++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void hosgeldiniz (string a , string b)
{
cout << "Programa hosgeldiniz !!!\nSayin : " << a << " " << b ;
}


int main (int sayiB , int sayii , string ad , string soyad )
{

cout << "Adinizi giriniz\n";
cin >> ad;
cout << "Soyadinizi giriniz\n";
cin >> soyad;
hosgeldiniz (ad , soyad);
cin >> sayii;
}
```

I searched the internet for the error but I don't understand the answer
I wrote it in eclipse and warnings !

```
'int main(int, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)' takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]

second argument of 'int main(int, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)' should be 'char **' [-Wmain]

third argument of 'int main(int, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)' should probably be 'char **' [-Wmain]
```

where's my fault?

Comment: Whoever told you that `main()` takes these arguments was wrong. See your C++ book for a full description of what arguments get passed to the `main()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters to a C++ program this way.  The signature for `main` should be either

```
int main()
```

Or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

In the second case, you can retrieve the arguments passed to the program by accessing the `argv` array, for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    cout << argv[i] << '\n';
```

See some documentation on how to parse arguments:

[How to parse command line parameters.](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/)

Comment: The signature for main can also be `int main()` with no arguments: that the one you've listed are the only two signatures that need to be supported, although compilers _may_ support others.

Comment: I realise that, but the question seems to be about passing arguments to main.  So I showed the relevant one.

Comment: Note that in a parameter definition (and *only* in a parameter definition), `char* argv[]` is equivalent to `char** argv`.